# Change language for a loaded tabbarController in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, multilingual

I want to change the language of the loaded tabbar controller from the app when the user selects the language from the tableview

Comment: Apple recommends that your app does not have it's own language selection. Just use the build in localization features of iOS and take the system language.

Comment: I like to second that. Do not try to defeat the Apple mechanisms, your app will behave unexpected for the user.

Comment: i am using localizedStringForKey method from the apple documentation for changing the language. initially i am getting the language code from the Device settings and then i am updating the view with language

Comment: then i am giving an option for the user to change the language from the app .the problem here my tabbarcontroller initially loads with then german language and when i am trying to change the language from the app settings by using  [[[window subviews] lastObject] removeFromSuperview]; which deletes the present tabbar and adds the same tabbar again to make the language changes but it is changing Can u guys help in this issue

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use the language the user applied to the whole OS. ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/StringsFiles.html))
Apple provides a nice macro called `NSLocalizedString`, you might want to check that out.

**Example:**

```
// Localizable.strings (German)
"Edit" = "Bearbeiten";

// code
label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", nil);
```